# Where are Rails objects and variables stored? Are users allowed to access them?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security

When we create new objects and variables in controller/view, where are they stored; at the client side in the browser, or at the server side?

I currently have information stored in objects and variables in both controller and views that I don't really want to be accessible by any user, for example, the authentication token etc.

Comment: In server memory. Your users won't be able to access your objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variables and objects themselves are stored on the server.

Remember that your web site is an application like any other, and variables and objects in code exist in that code only. You can choose to output their values in your views if you want to, but, if you choose not to, there is no way for the user to get at them.

Comment: +1, but I would make the distinction that variables are not stored in a database, but in the server's memory when that code is run.

Answer (score 0):

Variables and objects are in memory on the serving host ONLY if you don't write them to disk or a database or a mem-cache for persistence or data-sharing.

Whether those other stores can be accessed/hacked is a different question and not suitable for Stack Overflow.

Sometimes, on big clustered/load-balanced systems, we *HAVE* to write session data, shopping carts, cookies, etc., to some sort of shared-storage because we can't say for sure which host is going to receive the user's connection and all servers have to be able to pick up where another left off. Security is always an issue, but in those systems it becomes much harder because there are a lot more moving parts. But, for a small, single-host server, you should be fine.